# how to compare dates of 2 different models in django-rest , (onetomany relationship)

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

Models.py 
It has 2 models Dept and Emp
Each Dept has many Emps

```
 class Dept(models.Model):
        dept_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        dept_size = models.IntegerField()
        dept_formed_date=models.DateField(**allow_null)
        #owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='userum')


        def full_clean(self):
            if(self.dept_name.isdigit()):
                raise ValidationError("department name cant be in numbers !")
            if(self.dept_formed_date > date.today()):   
                raise ValidationError("the formation date cannot be in future !")
            if(Emp.emp_join_date < Emp.dept_formed_date):   
                raise ValidationError("Employee cannot join before department has even formed :/")


        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.full_clean()







    class Emp(models.Model):
        deptname = models.ForeignKey(Dept , related_name = 'emps')
        emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        emp_age = models.IntegerField()
        emp_join_date = models.DateField(**allow_null)
```

how to compare the dates of DEPT and EMP like emp_join_date should not be before Dept_form_date

Comment: Not really related to your question, but consider giving better names to your classes. "Department" is rather obvious (but harder to understand if written as "Dept"), and "Emp" is already meaningless. Is it "Employer" or "Employee"? Or - if seen without much context - does it mean "Empty" or "Emporer" or one dozens other things? Be expressive, code is read much more often than written.

Comment: yeah ! my bad  ,   Dept = Department . Emp = Employee ..

so , I need to compare dept_formed_date (Department formation date)  and emp_join_date(Employee joined date)  which are from 2 different models.
i have to validate it for avoiding user to enter date before department is created

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` method to do the kind of comparison I think you're asking about. Here's a little example in a single file for you to play with.

```
# Tested with Django 1.9.2
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from datetime import date
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

NAME = 'udjango'


def main():
    setup()

    allow_null = dict(null=True) # Not sure where this comes from, so I guessed.

    class Dept(models.Model):
        dept_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        dept_size = models.IntegerField()
        dept_formed_date=models.DateField(**allow_null)
        #owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='userum')


        def full_clean(self):
            if(self.dept_name.isdigit()):
                raise ValidationError("department name cant be in numbers !")
            if(self.dept_formed_date > date.today()):   
                raise ValidationError("the formation date cannot be in future !")
            if(self.emps.filter(emp_join_date__lt=self.dept_formed_date).exists()):   
                raise ValidationError("Employee cannot join before department has even formed :/")

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.full_clean()
            super(Dept, self).save()


    class Emp(models.Model):
        deptname = models.ForeignKey(Dept , related_name = 'emps')
        emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        emp_age = models.IntegerField()
        emp_join_date = models.DateField(**allow_null)

    syncdb(Dept)
    syncdb(Emp)

    d1 = Dept.objects.create(dept_name='Linens',
                             dept_size=3,
                             dept_formed_date=date(2014, 1, 15))
    Dept.objects.get(dept_name='Linens')  # Check that it saved properly.
    bob = d1.emps.create(emp_name='Bob', emp_age=19)
    d1.full_clean()

    bob.emp_join_date = date(2015, 12, 24)
    bob.save()
    d1.full_clean()

    bob.emp_join_date = date(2013, 12, 24)
    bob.save()
    try:
        d1.full_clean()
        assert False, 'Should have failed validation.'
    except ValidationError as ex:
        print(ex)

    print('Done.')


def setup():
    DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'WARN'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "WARN"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)

main()
```

You can use also use [F expressions in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters), if you don't want to load all the objects from the database.

> Django provides `F` expressions to allow such comparisons. Instances of `F()` act as a reference to a model field within a query. These references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of two different fields on the same model instance.

Paste this snippet in just before `print('Done.')`.

```
from django.db.models import F
d2 = Dept.objects.create(dept_name='Toys',
                         dept_size=5,
                         dept_formed_date=date(2014, 1, 16))
d2.emps.create(emp_name='Susan', emp_age=21, emp_join_date=date(2015, 12, 31))

bad_depts = Dept.objects.filter(emps__emp_join_date__lt=F('dept_formed_date'))
for dept in bad_depts:
    print(dept.dept_name)  # Linens

bad_emps = Emp.objects.filter(emp_join_date__lt=F('deptname__dept_formed_date'))
for emp in bad_emps:
    print(emp.emp_name)  # Bob
```